# How to write different html links for different css files?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have two different css files: 
one for pc wide screen and mobile landscape mode (style.css), and 
another for narrow pc screen and mobile portrait mode (mobileStyle.css). 
The problem is that style.css works for every pc screen size, and for mobile landscape, while mobileStyle.css works perfectly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 500px)" href="mobileStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 501px)" href="style.css" />
```

So, right now the only thing not working is the part where I don't get mobileStyle for pc screen at all. 
How do I change link's media so that I get mobileStyle for pc screen with max-width: 501px, and style.css for pc screen with min-width: 501px? (Actually tried writing that and it worked on pc, but then mobile didn't recognize different css)

Comment: It looks like `device-width` is deprecated according to the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp). Maybe use `min-width` instead?

Comment: Also, you might want to consider removing the `min-width` on the mobile style, since there's no stylesheet for all screens below 320px width

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 500px)" href="mobileStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 501px)" href="style.css" /> 
or 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 500px)" href="mobileStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(min-width: 501px)" href="style.css" />
makes it work fine on pc, but mobile portrait mode won't load mobileStyle now

Comment: What happens when you remove the ` and (min-width: 320px)` from the mobile style tag?

Comment: Still works fine on pc, but not on mobile. Same as with `min-width`

Comment: It could be that your phone or its browser doesn't support this syntax. Either way, you could put it inside one css file and use `@media` syntax inside to apply it to only the right sized browser screens. [Media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)